# Debugging Error while generating multiple templates from master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through a range of cells in a column and find non-blank cells to generate multiple template worksheets based on cell value in that specific range for further data transfer. however I am getting a debugging error, can anyone solve a problem? In the attached code "CETIN is the template worksheet[image: Debugging Error`]

```
Sub generateSheet()
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range
   Set sh1 = Sheets("CETIN")
   Set sh2 = Sheets("Combine")
      Range("A4:A600").Select
      Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$A$116").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("A4:A64").Select
Range("A4:A64").Select
Range("A4:A600").Select
Range("A116").Activate
Selection.Copy
Range("AT5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFilter

For Each c In sh2.Range("AT5", sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 46).End(xlUp))
    sh1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include which line it stops on when you click debug.

Comment: The last line ActiveSheet. Name - c.Value

Comment: Is there already a sheet with that name? Can't have 2 with the same name...

Comment: Yes there is one sheet named "CETIN" but, while generating multiple sheets the with the range specified another sheet named CETIN(2) is created.